# Getting a 404 error when uploading multiple files with a Perl CGI script

Tags: perl, file-upload, cgi

I have this very simple Perl script (actually much more complex but simplified to demonstrate the problem) :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw(:standard);
use Log::Log4perl;
use Data::Dumper;

Log::Log4perl::init_and_watch('log.conf', 10);
my $logger = Log::Log4perl->get_logger('UPLOADER');

print header;

my $req = CGI->new;
$logger->debug(Dumper($req->upload('files')));
```

I have a form on the client side that sends files using AJAX.

When I send a single file, everything works as expected.

However, when I send multiple files, I get a 404 error. And nothing is written in the log.

What am I missing ?

Tested with Chrome and Firefox.

Perl version : 5.20

Comment: Has nothing to do with the server-side script you posted